# How much is one 1945 German Mark to one 2016 Euro?

Tags: world-war-two, germany, post-war

Is there a way to figure out the exchange rate of one 1945 German mark to a 2016 Euro and/or U.S. dollar? (edited)

Comment: Are you really looking for an exchange rate or do you want a comparison of their buying power, e.g. a loaf of bread cost X reichsmarks in 1945 and costs Y Euros today?

Comment: Yeah-that is the sort of thing I am trying to find. @KillingTime

Comment: @tstols: Which one? Exchange rate or Consumer Price equivalence?

Comment: Exchange rate (that was the word i was looking for before I asked the question)

Comment: @tstols: The German Central Bank or the European Central Bank may, like the Reserve Bank of Australia has for Australia, have a web based inflation calculator for Germany. By way of example, the Australian one is: http://www.rba.gov.au/calculator/

Comment: @tstols Please edit your question to explain what you are really after. Comments are ephemeral and may be deleted.

Comment: Don't downvote the question! If you don't like it...ignore it. I would've deleted it but someone answered.

Comment: @tstols Sorry, but down voting and closing are an important part of curating the site to ensure it doesn't get clogged with trivial, unclear, and off-topic questions. If you're getting down voted or voted to close, it's up to you to work with us to improve your question using the suggestions in the comments. Or it may simply not be a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Reichsmark is worth exactly zero Euros today as the Reichsmark is not legal tender. You can go to eBay to find out what the asking price is for collectors, banknotes seem to be going for about US$2 regardless of denomination while silver coins are going for about US$4-5 to the Reichsmark.

If you were in an alternate universe where the Reichsmark and Euro co-existed you would get a similar answer, but for different reasons. Prior to the German capitulation, you would not have been able to exchange Reichsmarks for Euros due to currency controls. After the capitulation inflation made the Reichsmark so value-less that commerce was done through barter. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsmark) for a brief overview.